# fit and transform error on Cross validation and test data

Tags: python, scikit-learn, data-preprocessing

I need help with the code here. i am trying to fit and transform the train data and then transform the cross validation and the test data. but when i do that i get the error that - ValueError: X has 24155 features, but Normalizer is expecting 49041 features as input.

Can someone please help me to solve this issue.

my code snippet-

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import Normalizer
normalizer = Normalizer()

X_train_price_norm = normalizer.fit_transform(X_train['price'].values.reshape(1,-1))
X_cv_price_norm = normalizer.transform(X_cv['price'].values.reshape(1,-1))
X_test_price_norm = normalizer.transform(X_test['price'].values.reshape(1,-1))


print("After vectorizations")
print(X_train_price_norm.shape, y_train.shape)
print(X_cv_price_norm.shape, y_cv.shape)
print(X_test_price_norm.shape, y_test.shape)
print("="*100)
```

Comment: The transform function expects a 2D array as (samples, features). The error indicates that second dimension of `X_train['price']` and `x_cv['price']` or `x_test['price']` are not the same. Please add the code where you have split them.

Comment: Are you aware that `reshape(1, -1)` will transform all of your data into a single sample? I believe this is not what you want. Removing this method should give you your desired result.

Comment: @afsharov - appreciate the feedback, however without using the reshape(-1,1) below is the error i get - ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[399.99 215.92 510.88 ... 861.25  74.99 529.61].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.

Comment: @kaveh - appreciate your willingness to help! here is the code snippet where the data is split-from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, stratify=y)
X_train, X_cv, y_train, y_cv = train_test_split(X_train, y_train, test_size=0.33, stratify=y_train)

Comment: So, I think you should change the reshape to `(-1,1)` instead of `(1,-1)`. Since you have 1 feature (price) and many samples.

Comment: @kaveh- thanks a lot! yes changing the reshape values to (-1,1) worked!

Answer (score 2):

The transform function expects a 2D array as `(samples, features)`

The error indicates that second dimension of `X_train['price']` and `x_cv['price']` or `x_test['price']` are not the same.

As the code reflects, **you have 1 feature (price)**, and many samples. So, as the above explanation (samples, features), your input shape should be like `(n_samples,1)`, since you have one feature. Now, consider to change the reshape to `(-1,1)` instead of `(1,-1)`.

```
X_train_price_norm = normalizer.fit_transform(X_train['price'].values.reshape(-1,1))
X_cv_price_norm = normalizer.transform(X_cv['price'].values.reshape(-1,1))
X_test_price_norm = normalizer.transform(X_test['price'].values.reshape(-1,1))
```